# Rails 3 Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I've had this issue for a few days and looked over every tutorial and stack overflow.  I cannot seem to resolve.  I can't seem to use nested attributes that work.  I get an error with this form view.

```
 **Form View**


<%= form_for @trip, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
 <div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :start, :class => 'control-label' %>
<div class="controls">
  <%= f.text_field :start, :class => 'text_field' %>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
 <%= f.label :end, :class => 'control-label' %>
 <div class="controls">
  <%= f.text_field :end, :class => 'text_field' %>
</div>
```

```
<div class="control-group">
 <% f.fields_for :driver do |d| -%>
 <%= d.label :driver, :class => 'control-label' %>
 <div class="controls">
   <%= d.text_field :driver, :class => 'text_field' %>
 </div>
```

Model:

```
 class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :end, :start
     belongs_to :driver
     belongs_to :customer

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :driver
 end


class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 has_many :trips
  end
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having a column named 'end', that is likely to cause all sorts of trouble with the ruby parser. Try 'ends' or 'end_at'.

Comment: Thanks for the ends tip.  It's a parse error when this is used in the view:  <% f.fields_for :driver do |d| -%>
It references the driver model in the trip form.

Comment: So I didn't have an <end> tag and it was complaining.  Caught that but now I changed the trips to have a Can't mass-assign protected attributes: drivers

Comment: @user1485652 If you have solved your problem, please select the right answer or provide an answer. Upvoted the question for a good first question.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need closing end tag.
If you have the "Can't mass-assing procteted attributes: drivers" error you must declare "attr_accessible" on :drivers_attributes at the trip model.